# List of aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, sybase, aggregate-functions

Is there a way to fetch list of aggregate functions supported by a dbms using jdbc metadata or running any dbms specific query?

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server you can query XML which is in installation directory:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT @xml = x.y
FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlToolsData\1033\SQLCommonObjects.xml', SINGLE_BLOB ) x(y)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 'http://tempuri.org/SqlCommonObjects.xsd' AS ns )
SELECT
Category.Name.value('ns:DisplayName[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [Category],
[Function].Name.value('ns:Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') [Function],
[Function].Name.query('for $p in ns:Parameters/ns:Parameter return
concat($p/ns:Name[1],",")').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') Parameters

FROM @xml.nodes('//ns:Category[ns:DisplayName="Aggregate Functions"]')
AS Category(Name)
CROSS APPLY Category.Name.nodes('ns:Objects/ns:Function') [Function](Name)
```

Where after BULK statement you should give your folder(difference mainly is Program Files" and "Program_Files(x86)" and SQL server version (100 is 2008 in example)

Answer (score 0):

Your post has multiple DB tags, and each has system catalogs and/or an information schema that would let you know the list of procedures. Which table/view to query will differ from a DB engine to the next, however... (For instance, in Postgres you'd join pg_proc and pg_aggregate, since information_schema.routines won't tell you which procs are aggregates.)

It is usually safe to assume that typical aggregate functions (`sum()`, `count()`, `avg()`...) exist in all database implementations.

The only exception I'm aware of is Postgres, which does not support `any()`/`some()` due to [ambiguity in the syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT b1 = ANY((SELECT b2 FROM t2 ...)) FROM t1 ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fullproof, since it is not part of the JDBC spec. If you don't know what database engine you are using at runtime, your best bet is to submit a test query to the database and check whether or not it failed before using any aggregate function that may not be supported.

Comment: Many thanks everyone, my application needs to publish list of aggregate functions supported by underlying dbms. I am looking for such methods for sql-server, oracle, sybase and mysql. It is not part of JDBC spec, so I am looking for individual queries for these dbs. Last option would be to keep this list in a configuration file for all dbs.